Show actual HTTP error message in chrome developer tools
I am trying to make an HTTP Post request which results in a 500 http error with an error message which gives a full json body with "detail" including an actual error message in the body of the response.
Yet, when doing the same thing in chrome, it simply says 500 internal server error in Headers tab, and in response tab simply says failed to load response. How do I get the full json of the "response" even if there's an http error, so I can verify that it's the same error I got in Postman?
